# can I change emacs' default compile command?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

Emacs defaults to the command `make -k` when I run `compile`.  However, I pretty much *never* think it's useful to have `make` continue after errors, so I *always* remove the `-k` flag.  Is there a way to change the default in my `.emacs` so that it's just `make`?

Comment: The answer to "can I change X in Emacs" is YES for all values of X.

Comment: AShelley, exactly right.  The only real questions are, "HOW can I change X in Emacs?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(setq compile-command "make")
```

or similar in your .emacs should suffice.

For more info, type

```
C-h f compile
```

which describes what variables are used when M-x compile is called.

In there, you should see it calls compile-command and a

```
C-h v compile-command
```

tells you this defaults to "make -k". All above is a simplification, but all the info should be in those commands should you need to dig further.

Comment: For this purpose, is there an effective difference between `(setq compile-command ...)` and `(setq-default compile-command ...)`?

Comment: No idea Steve - C-h f setq and C-h f setq-default give a little more info, but can't really decipher.

Comment: @Steve, from the [Elisp Reference manual on `setq-default`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Default-Value.html): "If a SYMBOL is not buffer-local for the current buffer, and is not marked automatically buffer-local, `setq-default` has the same effect as `setq`."  `compile-command` is not automatically buffer-local, and it normally won't be buffer-local during execution of `.emacs`, so it normally won't make a difference.

Answer (score 8):

Since I need different compilers for different modes, I make use of the following snippet (here shown for javascript):

```lisp
(require 'compile)
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
                 (format "jshint %s" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))))
```

This runs "jshint " as my compile command.  I can then add hooks to other languages as well, and customize each according to my needs.

Comment: Note that you can also use `(file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)` for the file name without the extension.  For example, `(format "rustc %s && %s" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name))`.